# My Slider from material ui isn't continuous

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
      <Slider
        min={-10}
        max={10}
        style={{
          width: slider_width ? slider_width : "100px",
          color: "gray",
          marginLeft: "10px",
          marginRight: "10px",
        }}
        defaultValue={0}
        aria-labelledby="continuous-slider" // "discrete-slider-always"
        // step={1}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        value={value}
        track={false}
        onChange={check_color}
        ref={value_slider}
      />
```

```
  const [value, set_value] = useState(0);
  const check_color = (e, v) => {
    set_value(v);
  };
```

Why isn't it continuous? How do I make it so?

Comment: Please show function check_color

Comment: Slider is continuous here - https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-rgb-ozcm7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Viet updated post

Comment: @SarunUK the slider doesn't even slide in your link. I changed nothing.

Comment: Updated the code. Check now

Comment: @SarunUK ok, now it does slide. But it isn't continuous.

Comment: With min of -10 and max of 10 and the default step of 1, it only has 21 possible values. In order for it to appear continuous, you either need to widen the min/max range or reduce the step (e.g. `0.1` or `0.01`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, property `step` is 1. We can't set it to *null* because in that case

> the thumb can only be slid onto marks provided with the marks prop

All we can do is set a more appropriate value for it, like `step={0.001}`

Comment: So what is the purpose of this argument: `aria-labelledby="continuous-slider`

Comment: `aria-labelledby` represents `the id of the element containing a label for the slider`. (see [doc](https://material-ui.com/api/slider/))